# Remaining years, months, days using joda time (Android)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to obtaining remaining years, months, and days between two dates:
So I have used Joda Time to do so:

```
DateTime endDate  = new DateTime(2018,12,25,0,0);   
DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
Period period = new Period(startDate,endDate,PeriodType.yearMonthDay());

PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendYears().appendSuffix(" Year ").
            appendMonths().appendSuffix(" Month ").appendDays().appendSuffix(" Day ").appendHours()..toFormatter();

String time = formatter.print(period);
```

This gives me string time: 2 Year 4 Month 22 Day

However, I want integer values of each number of remaining years, months, days.
So, Instead of "2 Year 4 Month 22 Day", I want to set my variables:

```
int year = 2
int month = 4
int day = 22
```

Is there any way to obtain these values separately instead of obtaining one string? Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html)! There are getter methods for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same requirement once ,here is the code snippet

```
    LocalDate d=LocalDate.of(yy,mm,dd);
    LocalDate d2=LocalDate.of(yy, mm, dd);
    Period p=Period.between(d, d2);
    long day,month,year;
    day=p.getDays();
    month=p.getMonths();
    year=p.getYears();
    System.out.println(day+" : "+month+" : "+year);
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the methods provided by the DateTime  class and just subtract them. An example for years is below:

`int year = (int) dateTime#year#getField() - (int) dateTime2#year#getField()`

UNTESTED code!! I'll be looking into it later but the general idea is the same, get the field information then just subtract it to get a value